# Is there a browser game engine with options of payments?

Tags: browser

I would like to make some browser game, where you can buy stuff for real money. Is there any engine I could use? Or should I implement it by myself?

Comment: Isn't it really two frameworks?  One is the game engine, with the players having objects (won in game, or bought).  The other is your payment engine which can inject objects into the game engine.

Comment: I had through that maybe something like already exists.

Comment: Why is this down-voted? I want to get such engine too!

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE Unfortunately generic "What technology to use" questions are deemed [off-topic here](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/695/are-what-should-i-use-to-do-x-questions-really-on-topic-and-good). I recommend that you check out the chatroom for help with this type of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that (very probably) doesn't exist. I recommend using a framework/engine for the game itself and a library that allows payment via credit card or Paypal.